# Illegal bus range or name for logic function for instance "instMyAdder" of type 4 Bit Adder

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I am using QuartusII for designing a Four bit ripple carry adder. 
I keep getting this error:

```
Error (275022): Illegal bus range or name for logic function for instance "instMyAdder" of type 4 Bit Adder
```

My schematics are all correct, and you can verify yourself, and I am not using any buses, yet I still get this error. I have tried doing everything. I restarted, but I still get the same exact error. 

Here are my schematics:
**Full Adder Design:**

[image]

**4 Bit Adder Circuit:**

[image]

**2 Bit Adder Circuit**
[image]

I have done everything that I can to fix this problem, yet I still get the same exact error every single time. Altera suggests changing the names, but I'm not sure what that means:

[image]

Comment: If your lower schematic is called "1Bit Adder", then your upper schematic is calling for "2Bit Adder"s which don't exist.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it is a one bit full adder, but I named the schematics "2 bit Adder", but it doesn't matter. I fixed it for you.

Comment: I'm not a Quartus user, but I note that all the valid logic elements have instance names of the form instx, where x is numeric. Are you sure that "instmyAdder" rather than inst1 is a legal name?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, the name doesn't matter. You can choose any name that you want.

Comment: If you rename ```A[1]``` to ```A_1``` or ```A1```, does the issue go away? Also, you really should get into the habit of using zero indexing - ```0``` should be the first one.

Comment: The key part in the action text for the error is "remove the bus range" - ```[1]``` is a bus range, and you are basically ending up declaring the same signal on your adder 4 times (```A[1]```,```A[2]```, etc.) with different ranges which is not allowed. If you declared just one port as a bus (e.g. ```A[3..0]```) then it would be fine.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I made the changes you suggested, and the problem didn't go away. http://prntscr.com/abs9n1 and http://prntscr.com/abs9u1

Comment: Ahh! You have not only two spaces in the name of the module, but also a number at the start! ```4 bit Adder``` is not a valid HDL module name. ```Adder4bit``` would be, as would ```FourBitAdder```. Your comment of "You can choose any name that you want" is not at all true, you can only choose a name (not only instance, but module as well) which contains only ```A``` to ```Z```, ```_```, and also digits (as long as not the first character). The same goes for the ```2bit Adder``` module, which should be named something like ```FullAdder``` or ```Adder1bit``` (off topic: it is not a 2bit adder!).

Comment: @TomCarpenter YEESSSSSSS IT workssss. Thank you ssoooooooo much. I was going nuts!!! Now it all makes sense. If you care about reputation points, please just copy your comment into an answer box. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as it turns out is down to your choice of names for modules. You must remember that the schematic is first converted to HDL before it is synthesised (the conversion is internal), which means that you must use valid HDL module names.

In fact the error message [document page](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.1/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/egdfx_illegal_symbol_or_block_name.htm) gives you a link to a list of valid name characters and tells you to "Rename the logic function using legal name characters"

The list of allowed characters from that link is dependant on what the name is being used for, but to cut a long story short, basically the following is a list of valid characters:

- `a-z` `A-Z` (Alphabet) characters are permitted
- `0-9` (Digit) characters are permitted, but *only if* they are not the first character
- `_` (Underscore) is allowed, but *only if* not the first or last characters.

The following are invalid:

- (Space) is not allowed under any circumstances anywhere. Spaces are evil!
- `+-*/\&()...` (Symbols) Well basically any symbol except `_`.

---

In your design you had named the modules `4 bit Adder` and `2Bit Adder`. Both of these are invalid - they include spaces which are disallowed, and also have a digit as the first character which is also not allowed.

Valid options would be things like `Adder4Bit`, `FourBitAdder`, `Adder1Bit`, and so on.

---

It would probably also be worth your while diving into an HDL language - Verilog or VHDL. Even basic knowledge of the language would make life far easier for you - schematic/graphical entry will only get you so far (there are some topics on EE.SE that compare the differences).

As an example, your full adder in Verilog would be:

```
module Adder1Bit (
    input A,
    input B,
    input Cin,

    output S,
    output Co
);

assign halfSum = A ^ B; //A xor B

assign S = halfSum ^ Ci; //Make the full adder sum
assign Co = (halfSum & Ci) | (A & B); //Make the full adder carry

endmodule
```

---

Off topic: your `2Bit Adder` module is not a 2bit adder, it is a 1bit adder (a.k.a full adder).

See also: [Valid character names](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/reference/glossary/def_namechar.htm)